# Assigning a variable amount to a bunch of variables at once

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, integer, declare

Is there a better way to declare a single var value to a bunch of other variables at once. I am trying to declare `Int_amount` to all of the other variables down below. I am trying to minimize the code perhaps a for-loop would be a better option to declare all the values.

```
Int_amount = 100
Amount = Int_amount
S_Amount = Int_amount
L_Amount = Int_amount
NonC_Amount = Int_amount
NonC_S_Amount = Int_amount
NonC_L_Amount = Int_amount
```

Comment: How about this: Amount = S_Amount = L_Amount = Int_amount = .... = 100  You don't need any for-loop in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Amount, S_Amount, L_Amount, NonC_Amount, NonC_S_Amount, NonC_L_Amount = [Int_amount]*6`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it with a for-loop.

```
my_var = [
    'S_Amount', 'L_Amount', 
    'NonC_Amount', 'NonC_S Amount', 
    'NonC_L_Amount']
for i in my_var:
    globals()[i] = 100
```